# Solution/idea to call a function centrally and unified

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

So this one is a little bit hard to explain, but I'll try it:

I've got a div with the class `.boxes`. It's the wrapper of some looped elements. The looped elements have the class `.box`. Within this element, there are two more elements. One is the header with the class `.box-header` and one is the content with the class `.box-content`. I can open and close this elements with a click on it, so if it's closed, I just see the `.box-header` and if it's opened, I can see also the `.box-content`.

Here is a screenshot, which shows you how this looks like (grey container `.boxes` with the elements `.box` within in different states closed/opened):
[image]

I've got such lists in different components, so more than one time. The structure is mostly the same. So a example template of this looks like this:

```
<!--wrapper boxes-->
<div class="boxes">
    <!--looped element box-->
    <div class="box boxFor{{::box.id}}" ng-repeat="box in boxes" ng-class="{fill-container: boxes.length == 1}">
        <!--box header-->
        <div class="box-header" ng-click="box.open = !box.open">
            {{::box.name}}
        </div>
        <!--box content-->
        <div class="box-content" ng-if="box.open">
            <!--some content-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a example style of the classes:

```
.boxes {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: auto;
    .box {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex: 0 0 auto;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    .box-header {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        min-height: 30px;
        line-height: 20px;
        font-size: 16px;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .box-content{
        padding: 5px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
    .fill-container {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
    }
}
```

Now one requirement was, that everytime I open a box, it should take 50% of the height from his wrapper. So `.box` should have a `height: 50%;` of `.boxes`. This mean, I can see in maximum 2 opened boxes in the same time. When I open a third etc., it also should take the same height of 50% from .boxes, but I have to scroll to see it. If I just have one box, it should fill the whole container when I open it, this is solved with the `ng-class="{fill-container: boxes.length == 1}"` and works fine. I also implemented a function, which calculates and sets the 50% correctly to `.box` and it's also correct on the screen like in my screenshots. I did it like this:

In the ng-click of my .box-header, I call a function named `setBoxHeight()` in my controller, which calculates and sets me the correct height:

```
<div class="box-header" ng-click="box.open = !box.open; ctrl.setBoxHeight()">
    {{::box.name}}
</div>
```

The function looks like this:

```
setBoxHeight() {
    if (this.boxes.length > 1) {
        let boxHeaderHeight = $('.box-header').outerHeight();
        let halfHeight = Math.round($('.boxes').outerHeight() / 2);

        this.boxes.forEach((box: any) => {
            let element = $('.boxFor' + box.id);
            if (box.open) {
                element.height(halfHeight);
            } else {
                element.height(boxHeaderHeight);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If you compare my template and this function, it should be clear what happens. This works also fine. The problem is, that I have to implement it in every list I have on different controllers for different components. I would like to unify it and run it centrally for all lists. It should be a clean solution. I tried to build a external component and pass throught the boxes and their class names with some bindings and call once the function, something like this:

```
<my-component items="ctrl.boxes" header-class="'.box-header'" wrapper-class="'.boxes'"></my-component>
```

I'm pretty sure, there is a cleaner way to do this. I hope my question is clear enough. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could go for an all-CSS solution, and use the `flex-basis` property (see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis)). Basically, it sets the default size of flexible children; so you could set this to `50%`, so each `box` would take half the height of `boxes` (since your `flex-direction` is set to `column`).

There is of course some implementation to do to adapt this to your project, but it's worth a shot (and perhaps cleaner?).

Here is [a codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Lygdpj) to show you the trick.

*EDIT:* As @MrBuggy pointed out, this solution won't work in their case, since the `boxes` container doesn't have a fixed height.

Comment: Hi there. The problem I have with a css solution is, that .boxes hasn't got a height like in your example of 200px fix height given in css. So I have to get the height of .boxes when it's initialized, set it again and then I can get the 50% with css only..

Comment: I tried earlier a solution with css only (ng-class="{fill-container: boxes.length == 1, half-box: boxes.length > 1 && box.open}"), but the problem is, the opened boxes get the correct class, but because of there is no height for .boxes, the 50% can't get a value. And it's also not really a nice solution, if I have to get the height of .boxes with js when its initialized and then set it again with js, so my .box can work with it...

Comment: Ah, I see. Correct me if I'm wrong, the `boxes` container height is determined by the height of its `box` children?

Comment: .boxes has flex: 1 1 auto and uses the whole space of his parent, which also has flex: 1 1 auto, so there is a dynamic height...

Comment: Damn. True, this would prove difficult to use a percentage'd `flex-basis`. My bad then.

Comment: Yes, thats the reason why I had to switch to a JS solution... But thanks anyway! :)